# Decoding Thread-index/ConversationIndex email Header

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, encoding, mime-headers

I have been trying to decode **Thread-Index or ConversationIndex**, by following this [link](https://www.meridiandiscovery.com/how-to/e-mail-conversation-index-metadata-computer-forensics/) I have build conversation code...

It works fine but problem is when finding **differenceTime for childBlocks**

**if the first bit is '0'**(added high 15 bits and the low 18 bits), results are correct for this case, but I doubt that **I have mistake when 1st bit is 1**

I have also refered Microsoft [Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/tracking-conversations?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and **tried adding high 10bits and low 23 bit when 1st bit is ‘1’**.But the results are incorrect

Consider this example mentioned in this [link](https://www.meridiandiscovery.com/how-to/e-mail-conversation-index-metadata-computer-forensics/) : I have got the correct difference time, and here is flow…

```
Child Block Hex:0000CCBA30
Child Block Binary:0000000000000000110011001011101000110000  Length:40
Child Block Segerated:0 0000000000000001100110010111010 0011    0000
Since have 1st bit as '0' added high 15 bits and the low 18 bits:
Difference Time in Binary:0000000000000000000000000000001100110010111010000000000000000000
Difference Time in milliseconds:1373896
difference Time is : 00:22:53
Child Block Result Time:Wed Jan 02 22:53:58 IST 2013
```

But for Conversation Index: AQHWLRNo4NaOjvXU8EODe0ZotrA8B6itzaxf ,which I used for testing...

```
zero paded file time  : 1D62D1368000000
nano seconds          : 132342800426467328
Result Header Time :2020-05-18T12:54:02.646732800Z(Got this correct) 
Hex:A8ADCDAC5F
Child Block Binary    : 1010100010101101110011011010110001011111     Length:40
Child Block Segerated:1 0101000101011011100110110101100 0101    1111
Since have 1st bit as '1' added high 10 bits and the low 23 bits: 0000000000010100010101101110011011010110000000000000000000000000
Difference Time in NanoSeconds:5725048967004160
Difference Time in milliseconds:572504896700
difference Time is : 159029:08:16
Sum of header and child nanosecond:138067849393471488
Child Block Time   : 2038-07-09T18:02:19.347148800Z
```